# build git branch with snapshot dependency in TeamCity

Tags: teamcity

Build which depends on snapshot dependency uses wrong branch.

Main VCS(for nugets, builds, code analysis):
`default branch: develop, +:refs/heads/*`

Environment 1 VCS:
`default branch: master`
And here I have snapshot dependency to build from `Main VCS`. And when "Environment 1 VCS" build it uses `default` branch from "Main VCS".

How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

build configuration has `teamcity.build.branch` parameter, which responsible for which branch will be used.

So, Environment 1 VCS  create **Configuration Parameter** which will change your parent dependency configuration branch.

```
name = reverse.dep.*.build.branch
value = %teamcity.build.branch%
```

So, when you run your child configuration and select any brunch, then `teamcity.build.branch`=your branch

[image]

[reverse.dep](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Predefined+Build+Parameters) means Overriding Dependencies Properties for your parent configuration. It means you parent configuration will run on some branch.

Comment: Yep, it works when I manualy select branch from "Run" dropdown. But if I click "Run" at build is uses `develop` instead of `master` in dependencies.

Comment: did you save this parameter or just add every time when click run?

Comment: Save, in VCS 1 build configuration. But agnet do not know what is it

Comment: it's configuration parameter. the agent should not know anything. if you have more then 1 VCS  root, you have to set `reverse.dep.vcs_name_2.*.build.branch `